# Gradle Multi Module Product : Compiling module which depends on another

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I am coming from Maven workd and new to Gradle.I have multi-module Gradle product with following modules:

```
"cdna-common"
'cdna-data-access'
"cdna-api-dto"
"cdna-api-module"
"cdna-request-executor-module"
```

[image]

my root **settings.glade** looks like this:

```
rootProject.name = 'cdna-one-platform'

include "cdna-common"
include 'cdna-data-access'
//include "cdna-api-dto" //commented temporary
include "cdna-api-module"
//include "cdna-request-executor-module" //commented temporary
```

gradle file for module '**cdna-data-access**' is :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M6'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }

}

ext['hibernate.version'] = '5.2.11.Final'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.company.cdna'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

jar {
    baseName = 'cdna-one-data-access'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}
a

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm')
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-search-orm' , version: '5.8.2.Final'
    compile group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'lucene-analyzers-kuromoji' , version: '5.5.5'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('com.h2database:h2')
}
```

Module '**cdna-common**' depends on '**cdna-one-data-access**' and gradle file looks like :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

group = 'com.company.cdna'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

jar {
    baseName = 'cdna-one-commons'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }

}

dependencies {
    compile project(':cdna-data-access')
}
```

When I compile the module 'cdnHowever,cess' using '**gradlew cdna-data-access:build**' , it compiles without any error.

However , when I try to compile the module 'cdna-common' using '**gradlew cdna-common:build**' , it gives following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':cdna-common:compileClasspath'.
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter//spring-boot-starter-.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter//spring-boot-starter-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter//spring-boot-starter-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter//spring-boot-starter-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter//spring-boot-starter-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter//spring-boot-starter-.jar
  Required by:
      project :cdna-common > project :cdna-data-access
> Could not find mysql:mysql-connector-java:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java//mysql-connector-java-.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java//mysql-connector-java-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/mysql/mysql-connector-java//mysql-connector-java-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/mysql/mysql-connector-java//mysql-connector-java-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/mysql/mysql-connector-java//mysql-connector-java-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/mysql/mysql-connector-java//mysql-connector-java-.jar
  Required by:
      project :cdna-common > project :cdna-data-access
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa//spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa//spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa//spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa//spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa//spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa//spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-.jar
  Required by:
      project :cdna-common > project :cdna-data-access
```

Any tips of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to change spring-boot version ?

Comment: but with same version , i can build the module "cdna-data-access" using , "'gradlew cdna-data-access:build"